# set function is not working in another window

Tags: python, tkinter

I get data from database (48, 'aciloc', '20', 'Sonu', '2610', '25', '1234', '6%', '6%', '12%', '40.0', '12/02/2021', 10, '10', 30.0, 10.0, 40.0)
I want to set these data in textvaribles in another window

I get this error `'Entry' object has no attribute 'set'`

```
def update_med(self):

          conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="Sonu@1997",database="pharmacy")
          my_cursor=conn.cursor()
          my_cursor.execute("select * from fharma where bill = %s and name = %s",(self.bill_no.get(),self.p_name.get()))
          row = my_cursor.fetchone()
          print(row)
          conn.commit()
          self.do_update(row)
          conn.close()
  def do_update(self,row):
          
          
          self.fetched_data = Tk()
          self.fetched_data.geometry("1550x800+0+0")
          self.fetched_data.title("UPDATE MEDICINE")
          s = row
          print(s[2])
          
          
          
          updated_data=LabelFrame(self.fetched_data,bd=10,relief=RIDGE,padx=20,text="Medicine Entry In Stock",fg="red",font=("arial",12,"bold"))
          updated_data.place(x=0,y=5,width=1220,height=250)
          
          self.bill_num = StringVar()
          bill=Label(updated_data,font=("arial",10),text="Bill No.:",fg="black")
          bill.grid(row=0,column=0)
          billnum=Entry(updated_data,bd=4,textvariable=self.bill_num,relief=RIDGE,width=20)
          billnum.grid(row=0,column=1)
          self.bill_num.set(s[2])
```

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what is wrong: `Entry` widgets don't have a `set` method. Also, the code you posted will not give you that error.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that has as few lines as possible to reproduce the problem. For example, you can replace all of the database code with some hard-coded values.